# Edit customer creation in Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I want to edit the creation of a customer, I want to add a field during the creation. During the creation the service ***"sylius.controller.customer:createAction"*** is called in `security.yml`

```
sylius_shop_register:
    path: /register
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.customer:createAction
        _sylius:
            template: "@SyliusShop/register.html.twig"
            form: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Customer\CustomerRegistrationType
            event: register
            redirect:
                route: sylius_shop_account_dashboard
            flash: sylius.customer.register
```

However I checked a lot of Sylius services I didn't find it.
How can I access to this service to custom the creation ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think I did now

Answer (score 0):

You should customize the form and not the controler.
You can find detailed information here ([sylius customizing form](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/form.html))

The idea is:

1. Create a form extension:

   ```
   final class CustomerRegistrationType extends AbstractTypeExtension
       {
           /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
       {
           // Adding new fields works just like in the parent form type.
           $builder->add('YourField', TextType::class, [
               'required' => false,
               'label' => 'app.form.customer.yourfield',
           ]);
       }
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function getExtendedType()
       {
           return CustomerRegistrationType::class;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register this extension as a service in the `AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`
3. Add according translations, and add a new template to show your new field

Regards